# How to have a forward slash in a file name?

Tags: files, filename

I understand that this will likely break and confuse the hell out of my system, but is it possible to name or rename a file so that it has `/`s in its name (this is needed for a file which needs to go to an equally crazy server - well, sort of, it's more of a crazy workaround)? I am running Ubuntu GNOME 15.10 with GNOME 3.18, and I have tried to do this with most programs, and they either make a folder with the file because they treat what is before the `/` as the folder and what is after it as the file name, or just give me an error.

**Reason:**

The specific reason why I need it is because I set up a server which is stubborn and now won't change it's mind about where its config file is. However I accidentally put a `/` in the name of the file so it believes that the config file rather being in `~/configuration/files/config1.conf` is in `~/configuration/files/con/fig1.conf`... So you might say that I should just create a folder in `files` and call it `con` and then have the config file called `fig1.conf`, however the server doesn't even currently allow the creation of new directories or anything really... So I think that my only hope is going to be to put the forward slash in the file name for now until it goes out of its lock down mode.

Comment: Interesting question!

Comment: POSIX forbids "/" and NULL in filenames ;)

Comment: Oh and if you want to delete it: use the inode to reference the file

Comment: Sounds like a very elaborate approach to avoid learning how to configure your server :/

Comment: @Tyler: No, learning how to configure it is what got me in this mess in the first place, because I decided to make a script to automate the configuration and it seems that some of the safety measures are becoming rather annoying... :P

Comment: @ParanoidPanda What is this "lock down mode" you speak of? I'm not aware of any such feature on Ubuntu...

Comment: Next thing you'll be trying to put in a file name is a real live bamboo shoot ;)

Comment: Boot the server off a USB drive, or pull the disk from the server and plug it into another system. Then mount it and fix the config.

Comment: I'm curious, which "crazy server" wouldn't allow you to stop it and reconfigure?

Comment: @IlmariKaronen: Yeah, I think I'm gong to end up doing that...

Comment: @Cyle: Oh, that's something I made... :D

Comment: @MarkoBonaci: Clearly it is the server I configured. :P

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> Is it possible to name or rename a file so that it has /s in its name [...]?

No, it's not, for obvious reasons.

E.g. consider you have a directory containing:

- a directory named "foo" containing a file named "bar"
- a file named "foo/bar"

```
/path/to/foo/bar # file named "bar" in the directory named "foo"
/path/to/foo/bar # file named "foo/bar"
```

Referencing either of the two would be ambiguous.

If you're curious as to where the limitation is imposed, that's at the kernel level, in order to comply with the filesystem's specifications.

In general, any character can be used in a filename aside from `/` (unicode `002f`) and `\0` (unicode `0000`), and filenames such as `.` and `..` are disallowed as well.

Comment: And what would happen if I got a file with a forward slash in the name from another filesystem and put it onto my machine?

Comment: And is there now way at all of bypassing this and putting a file there? I mean, what if I loaded if off a LiveUSB onto the machine while the machine was not on but the disk mounted?

Comment: @ParanoidPanda http://superuser.com/q/603792/427197

Comment: @ParanoidPanda that would make the filesystem incomptatible with POSIX ;-)

Comment: @ParanoidPanda If the file does indeed have a `/` in its name on the underlying file system I can imagine one of two possible outcomes. Either a programmer was paranoid about corrupted data coming back from the file system and reported this as an error. Or the `/` would be visible all the way through to user mode. However that would only make the file name visible. Any attempt to `stat` the file to get more information or `open` it would cause the kernel to parse the file name and interpret the `/` as a directory separator. Hence you would not be able to access the file, even if you can see it

Comment: What about if you referenced it with `foo\/bar` to escape the slash?

Answer (score 0):

In the Mac OS terminal, you can replace the slash with a colon (:) when you're renaming, and when you view the file in Finder (graphic file manager) the file name should have the slash at the place you typed a colon. This probably also works in Linux.

Comment: Have you actually tested this on Linux?

Answer (score -1):

It CAN be done,  not easily,  not well,  and not recommended (it creates problems when trying to remove the file.

Simply use a unicode substitute. It's better explained at linuxanswers.com.

`bash` shell example using the unicode "fractional slash" `U+2044`

```
bash# >test$'\xe2\x88\x95'file
bash# ls --show-control-chars
test∕file
bash# ls
test???file
```

I don't know if however the server can then access the file,  but Ubuntu can.  You may have to alias it at the server end,  if possible.  (Haven't had to touch a Windows installation since the days of Windows 95).

Comment: Could provide the unicode substitute to use?

Comment: This won't actually help the OP, since their "server" is expecting an actual ASCII slash, not a Unicode character that just happens to *look like* a slash.