# Gettting error The folder contents could not be displayed when saving file

Tags: libreoffice

How to save a file when have a trailing slash like this:

> GNU/Linux Distro

I tried to save the file but i get this error message:

> The folder contents could not be displayed
>
> Error when getting information for file “/home/agus/Documents/GNU”: No such file or directory

Comment: In what program are you trying to save the file?

Comment: Related: [How to have a forward slash in a file name?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/719916/how-to-have-a-forward-slash-in-a-file-name)

Answer (score 0):

The slash "/" is not part of the file name. It separates folder and file names. In your case, you are trying to save a file with the name "Linux Distro" into a folder "GNU". If the folder "GNU" does not exist in the current working directory, which in your case is “/home/agus/Documents/", then the save operation will fail.

To have the save operation succeed, first create a folder "GNU" in the folder "Documents". You need to do this from within your file manager. Creating folders from within a "File save" dialog is not supported.